# Optimisation problem, finding the minimum time possible.

Tags: calculus

[the image for the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOeOs.png)
A tiger wants to scare a buffalo, well, to scare it to death!
The tiger is on the opposite side of a river to the peacefully grazing buffalo 10 m further downstream, AB. The river is w = 5 m wide. In water the tiger can swim at Vs = 1 m/s and on land it can run at Vr = 4 m/s. To get to the buffalo and scare it, the tiger swims in a diagonal straight line across the river to point X and runs along the shore in a straight line to the Buffalo at B.

a.Solve the problem in the general case in terms of the two speeds, Vs and Vr , the width of the river,´w, and the distance the buffalo is downstream from the tiger, d. Are there any special cases to consider?

I am confused about the part where I need to consider special cases, i know that the function depends on the ratio of Vs and Vr and not the values, of Vs and Vr. However, I am unable to figure out a domain. My teacher said that I need to consider the ratio 1.1 and did not provide any further explanation.

My attempt is included here. 
[my attempt, couldn't post more images since apparently i don't have a good reputation here ;)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOeOs.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You found the issue, you just didn't finish.

1. If $v_r > v_s$ then the optimal $x$ is $\dfrac{v_s{}w}{\sqrt{v_r²-v_s²}}$.
2. Otherwise the optimal $x$ is $d$.

For each case you need to calculate the value of $t_\text{min}:=t(x)$, where x is optimal.

For the second case you have $t_\text{min}=\dfrac{\sqrt{w^2+d^2}}{v_s}$.

Comment: THANK YOU!! :), can you please elaborate on the part where you say, ''Then you need to plug the value of the optimal x in each case in the formula for t(x)'' . The value of the optimal x is 1.30 m (that's what i calculate it to be at least). Why should i plug x in when i am asked to write a general solution?

Comment: Ah alright, got it!!